# Vue App automated rebuild on file change in production mode

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, npm

So I built a vuetify app. It is connected to a cloud and should load new images dynamically, after they are uploaded. The images will only be visible for the after running the container due to a volume connection. While compiling there are no pictures for the app to see. And copying the images to the app and then compile would still not allow updating to new images, without stopping the container.

In dev mode it works fine, as it compiles again when something changes. I want to use a cronjob to run a python script, which indexes all images in a json and then if the json changes, it should rebuild.

My current Dockerfile (without insalling python and without cronjob) is:

```
# build environment
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY prod_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Now after researching for a while, I found 'npm run watch', but can anyone recommend this and how would I need to build my container, due to the changes in the ngnix needed for the router to work?

I mean is there any other possibility to make the app recompile on changes?

I tried installing npm/vue in the nginx container and the manually rebuild it, copy it to the right folder and so on, but it's a mess and it didn't want to load the images (don't know the exact reason something with format and correct loader, but works in dev mode, so idk).

Comment: I'm using a bash script based on `inotifywait` for similar purposes. Check [Script to monitor folder for new files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files) and [How to use inotifywait to watch a directory for creation of files of a specific extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323901/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-watch-a-directory-for-creation-of-files-of-a-specific) threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution.

I have a cronjob which triggers a python script every minute. This script just indexes the directory and all files in it.
Then I have an incron job which is triggered, when the output of the python script changes. The incron job runs npm run build.